# Why association resource is not binding

Tags: spring-data-rest

I am using spring data rest. When I try to create a resource using post method with application/json using following object, association resources are not binded although they are already present in db

```
{
screeName : 'adsaf',
screenType : {
   screenTypeId : 1,
   screenTypeName : 'Fixed'
}
}
```

Why? Is there anyother way of accomplishing this task other than separately setting associations? I am asking this question because if I manually receive this form in a controller and use ObjectMapper to deserialize and then save this object, all associations would be set. Then why its not happening in spring data rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using Custom HttpMessageConverter. check following thread.

[Creating Resource with references using spring data rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274219/creating-resource-with-references-using-spring-data-rest/46276043#46276043)

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data REST [works](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.resource-discoverability) with links to resources so you have to change your payload to something like this:

`POST http://localhost:8080/api/screens`

```json
{
    "screenName": "adsaf",
    "screenType": "http://localhost:8080/api/screenTypes/1"
}
```

If you need to save `ScreenType` when you POST `Screen` object too, you should turn off the exporting of your `ScreenType` repository:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface ScreenTypeRepo extends JpaRepository<ScreenType, ...> {
}
```

and add cascading (at least `PERSIST`) to your `screenType` field in `Screen` entity:

```java
public class Screen {
    //...
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    ScreenType screenType; 
}
```

That's mean that `ScreenType` will be managed by `Screen`. In this case you would be able to use a payload like this:

`POST http://localhost:8080/api/screens`

```json
{
    "screenName": "adsaf",
    "screenType": {
        "screenTypeName": "Fixed"
    }
}
```

to create a new ScreenType simultaneously with Screen.