# How can I change the foreign key with a PATCH-Request in Spring-boot?

Tags: java, ajax, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am using spring-data (and spring-data-rest ...)and want to change a foreign key with a patch request (Not using the HAL-Browser, because I have to send that request with ajax)
Does anybody of you know how I can accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each resource is identified by its url. So suppose you have a person who has city. person resource is identified by url /api/persons/1 and the city that you want to assign to this person is identified by /api/cities/7. Then send a patch request to /api/persons/1 with following json:

```
{    
   "city" : "http://localhost:7070/api/cities/7" 
}
```

Comment: Can I somehow change it, that I don't have to know the link, but only the ID? Somehow with projections?

Comment: associations are always identified by url in spring data rest. You can write your own message converter if you wish to change this behavior to any thing you want. See this for reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274219/creating-resource-with-references-using-spring-data-rest/46276043#46276043

Comment: So with that solution I can achieve the goal of updating the foreign-key (to city) in person (for instance 1) to a new foreign-key (f.i. 5)?

So that I just have to send a PATCH-Request where the attribut "city" has the new ID 5?

Comment: also if you have the foreign key, why not build the url from this foreign key before sending patch request? I mean its pretty standard that url would be {basepath} + foreign key

Comment: I have generalized update functionality in a library. you can view it at https://github.com/ArslanAnjum/asaStarter and https://github.com/ArslanAnjum/angularSpringApi

Comment: Yeah, building the url would be an easy solution. But I thought that there must be a way to just send the new foreign key. The solution with the link seemed a bit too "I just do this, though there is a much better and standardized solution and I don't know what I am doing" to me^^

Comment: share if you find a better solution.

Comment: I think you think that the sentence "I just do this, thought there ... " is against you, but that's not the case! I was just explaining that I thought this and why I came to search for another solution. 
Now I know that this is the standardized solution, thanks to you!

Comment: ah. not at all. I am also in search of some standard way to do that and may be in some next spring release they may provide that.

Comment: Can I ask you more about spring? You seem to have already invested a decent amount of time in spring.

Unfortunately I haven't got enough reputation for chatting!

Comment: yeah sure. you can join this chat room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/72007/spring?tab=general

Comment: or add me on skype. id is "arslansher"